# Event Handler in c# works only on new controls

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

This is in WinForms using c#.
Have a form with 10 radio buttons viz..car,bike,train,bus etc. And a label with text "XYZ".All in the same group box.
I wrote the following common method to hide the text on  check of a radio button.

```
private void Hide_radio(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadioButton rb = sender as RadioButton;
    if (rb != null)
       label1.Text="";              
}
```

Strangely, calling the event as in the below way(just under initialize component), works only on few radios and not all. When I drag a new radio, it works on it. [Strictly drag n drop. No new code added or removed.]

```
foreach (Control gb1c in groupBox1.Controls)
{
    if (gb1c is RadioButton)
    {
        RadioButton rb = gb1c as RadioButton;
        rb.CheckedChanged += new MouseEventHandler(Hide_radio);
        break;
    }
}
```

I have checked the designer.cs and the code for all radios is the same.
So basically, the event handling is working on only few and new radios but not all.
Why is C# acting so childish..

Comment: "Why is C# acting so childish" - it only does what you tell it to do.

Comment: you do not need a break statement what you need is to create a method that checks for what you need, also Instead of Casting first I would personally Check to see if Control is of a particular type also in a method you would need to make a recursive call ..`Why is C# acting so childish` it's not the Language that is its' probably the `user / coder`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are breaking foreach cycle on first event subscription. Remove "break" from the cycle.

Comment: Ahhh! So it was the child in me then...

Removing the breaks worked.

Thank you again every one for the quick posts.

Answer (score 2):

Your use of `break;` exits the loop, so any controls that do not yet have the event handler assigned will not get the event handler. This is not C# acting childish, this is C# doing exactly what you tell it to.